# Terraform state sync with external changes

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I have terraform managing my infrastructure in Azure. However, there are cases where the state can get out of sync when other services are changing the infrastructure as well.

For example, I have terraform create an Application Gateway. But I also have an AKS cluster with AGIC enabled, which dynamically updates/changes rules, listeners, etc. inside of Application Gateway. So if terraform is re-run after AGIC makes some changes, terraform doesn't know and wants to reset to the default config it knows about.

Maybe this isn't possible, but is there an automated way to sync the two? It's kind of unfeasible to have to go into the terraform config and manually add the changes AGIC makes every time it does so. At this point, is it even worth managing Application Gateway with terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to create the `Application Gateway` with Terraform, you should probably use the Lifecycle Meta-Argument [ignore_changes](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes) on the attributes that will be modified by AKS. It is not perfect, but at least they can share their responsibilities without overwriting each other.

> The ignore_changes feature is intended to be used when a resource is
> created with references to data that may change in the future, but
> should not affect said resource after its creation. In some rare
> cases, settings of a remote object are modified by processes outside
> of Terraform, which Terraform would then attempt to "fix" on the next
> run. In order to make Terraform share management responsibilities of a
> single object with a separate process, the ignore_changes
> meta-argument specifies resource attributes that Terraform should
> ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object.

For example :

```
resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "example" {
  ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      http_listener,
      request_routing_rule,
      backend_http_settings
    ]
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the behavior I want.